# How to run a shell script [.sh] from WinSCP process in C# .NET

Tags: c#, shell, winscp, winscp-net

I have done the following steps successfully:

1. I have created an WinSCP [Process] in C# .NET
2. Created a Session of a user on LINUX-server [Using SFTP Protocol]
3. Downloaded the files using `GetFiles(........);`

The thing I want to add to my App is that:

- Give that process a command to run a shell-script [already uploaded on the server]
- I tried this `session.ExecuteCommand("sh /fol1/fol1_1/abc.sh");`
   but giving no results/impacts

Comment: Though I'm still confused by your reference to `Process` and `winscp.StandardInput`. That does not go well with WinSCP .NET assembly. It would really help, if you post your code.

Comment: Thanks @MartinPrikryl . Updated the Question's last bullet. No error while running but the files are not being created in the directory using abc.sh . Though the abc.sh is working when i manually run it from putty

Comment: When running in PuTTY, do you execute it using the same syntax (`sh /fol1/fol1_1/abc.sh`) from the root folder?

Comment: i go to the directory using cd first then simply: sh abc.sh

Comment: So try the same with WinSCP: `session.ExecuteCommand("cd /fol1/fol1_1; sh abc.sh");`

Comment: I tried it, thanx it work but before i had to do: cd ../;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To execute a shell command on the server using WinSCP .NET assembly, use the [`Session.ExecuteCommand`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_executecommand):

```
session.ExecuteCommand("sh abc.sh");
```

This will work with the SCP and the SFTP (with limitations) protocols only.
See https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_executecommand#remarks